# NVIDIA RTX GPU Driver installation in AWS for Omniverse

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, gpu, nvidia, omniverse

I have laptop with NVIDIA Quadro T2000 GPU but this GPU is not support with the Omniverse.[see screenshot]
So I am trying with creating AWS EC2 Instance with G4dn.2xlarge instance type with windows server 2022.
Note: I want to Omniverse XR which only support Windows OS.
After creating EC2 instance in AWS, I have install NVIDIA driver from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx .

```
Driver Details are as follows:
Product Type: Tesla 
Product Series: T-series
Product: Tesla T4
Operating System: Windows 10
CUDA Toolkit:11.7
```

Driver is successfully installed I can see the status of installed, But still when I am trying to open any app in Omniverse, for ex. Omniverse create/XR, each and every app got crashed as soon as we launch.
I can see following logs in the terminal:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZE2c.png)

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: FYI this question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow (it's not a programming question). Perhaps post to superuser. Just be sure to post properly-formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.